# Drawing 5 values from N(0,1) and changing the order of the drawn values. Sama data generating process but different likelyhood?

Tags: normal-distribution

I was wondering today of a specific problem. Let's I draw 5 values from a normal distibution with `mu = 0` and `sigma = 1`. In this case I think it would be correct to says the the likelyhood of seeing `1, 1, 1, 1, 1` is higher than say `2, 2, 2, 2, 2`.

However, if I am asked: which data stems more likely from 5 draws of a normal disribution? `1, 2, 1, 2, 1` or `1, 1, 1, 2, 2` ?

Would the correct answer be that both data sets were equally likely generated by a normal disribution?

Comment: They are equally likely to be drawn i.i.d. from a normal distribution (though it is improbable that all the values would be integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchangeability is property of the joint probability of a sample $ \textbf{X} = (X_1,\dots,X_n)$ to be invariant for any permutation:

$$
p_{\textbf{X}}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = p_{\textbf{X}}(x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})
$$

for any permutation $\sigma \in \mathcal{G}(n)$.

If your variables $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ are drawn independently and are identically distributed (as in your example), then they are exchangeable because the joint density is the product of each density :

$$
p_{\textbf{X}}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i)
$$

which is invariant for any permutation.

For your last question then yes the *likelihood* of both sample will be the same.

Note that exchangeable does not imply iid.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So once I reorder value I cannot claim that they are iid anymore, correct?

Comment: The likelihood of $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ will be the same as for the sorted vector $(x_{1,n},\dots,x_{n,n})$ for the iid sample $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ because the latter is a permutation of the former. However the ordered sample $(X_{1,n}, \dots, X_{n,n})$ is not exchangeable because the joint density is $n! \prod p(x_i)$ for $x_1 < \dots < x_n$ but zero otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming random sampling from $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ the *probability* 
$P(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1, X_3 = 1, X_4 = 2, X_5 = 2) = 0.$

If $\varphi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-0.5z^2}$ is the standard normal density function, then for
independent sampling the joint density function is
$$\varphi(1)\varphi(1)\varphi(1)\varphi(2)\varphi(2).$$

In R, the standard normal density is written `dnorm`. So the
function displayed above could be evaluated as 0.5687654, to seven decimal places.
Because multiplication is commutative, the order of the factors is irrelevant.

```
 prod(pnorm(c(1,1,1,2,2)))
[1] 0.5687654
```

In mathematical expressions, the likelihood function of a random sample is often
written as the product of density functions: 
$$L(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\,|\mu) = \prod_{i=1}^5 f_X(x_i|\mu).$$ 
Often $L(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\,|\mu)$ is viewed as a function of parameter $\mu,$ where data values $x_i$ have been observed and so have known values.

However, in most contexts, the
likelihood function is defined only up to a constant multiple, so the
constants of integration need not be written. Thus, for $\mu$ unknown and $\sigma=1$
the likelihood function might be written as
$$L(z_1, \dots, z_5|\mu) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^5e^{-0.5\sum_{i=1}^5 (z_i-\mu)^2} \propto e^{-0.5\sum_{i=1}^5 (z_i-\mu)^2},$$
where the symbol $\propto$ (read "proportional to") indicates that the
constant is not displayed.

If you are finding the parameter value $\mu$ that maximizes a likelihood function, the constant factor is not
relevant. For this reason likelihood functions are often not evaluated numerically.